# SOQL query to retrieve contactid from object Users

Tags: soql, salesforce-id

A simple but stupid question here:

I know we can query contactid from user as

```
    select contactid from user
```

but why I can't see a field of 'contactid' from the object User, instead, I can only see the field of 'Contact'?

[image]

Comment: when using soql, always check the api names against the [SFDC Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm?search_text=user_

Comment: It's not a stupid question! It's not obvious why it works like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a standard Lookup relationship, the field API name is always appended by 'Id' at the end. It refers to the contact field only.